# Улучшение поиска по базе данных

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Стандартный код для поиска:

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM movie WHERE title LIKE '%$query%'");
```

При поиске **чужой: завет** результат - **Чужой: Завет, Чужой 2**. А при поиске **чужой завет** (без двоеточия), ничего не находит.  Можно  ли это как-то обойти?

П.С. **Boolean Full-Text Search**  не   подходит, он не находит цифры, например **1+1**. Да и он ищет все совпадения.

Comment: Что будет если написать запрос `'`

Comment: **Ничего   не найдено**

Comment: А если `' OR 1=1;--`

Comment: Подождите, это куда?

Comment: В $query . . ..

Comment: Хм, что бы **' OR 1=1;--** нашлось, оно должно быть в БД, я добавил это значение в БД, и сделал поиск по нему, результат - 0

Comment: А   так же,  в базе есть заголовок **Я, Ты, Он, Она**  - по точному совпадению не находит

Comment: Чтобы искало так, как вы хотите, нужно строку поиска делить на слова и искать каждое слово через `OR`. И ещё вам @andreymal очень сильно намекал на sql injection

Comment: @ArchDemon я так  и думал, что это  иньекция,  но  никаких  изменений, вроде,    не произошло. Мне   не  совсем понятно, как  можно сделать сделать запрос в mysql по  массиву из  слов.